# for D structs is opAssign necessary/useful and if so when

Tags: d

In TDPL 7.1.5.1 there is discussion of Widget w2 being assigned to w1 and the author states "Assigning w2 to w1 field by field assigns w2.array to w1.array—a simple assignment of array bounds, without actually copying the array contents. This needs fixing because what we want is to create a duplicate of the array in the source Widget and assign that duplicate to the target Widget." From what I have seen, if you have written a postblit, then the default opAssign calls your postblit. It then seems that this is incorrect in the book, or at a minimum suspect advice. Further, it seems if you have created a postblit there is no need to create an opAssign. Is this a correct assessment of the issue?

Assuming writing less code is good, what is the circumstance for implementing opAssign for structs?

Answer (score 4):

the first thing that comes to mind is assigning something to a struct which isn't of the struct type (like a `double` to a `Angle` struct)

also when there is a external resource needed unique for each struct (pure value semantics) you can then use the `opAssign` to copy the contents directly into the old resource instead of discarding in the destructor and then reallocating in the postblit

this last use is only useful when deallocation/allocation of the resource is a lot more expensive than the deep copy (TBH I can't really think of one right now)

Comment: This sounds like confirmation that in general you would not want one. The conversion of a different type is a good example when you would. Honestly, I did not follow the external resource part of the explanation. If you want value semantics and have external resources (say a file handle), wouldn't you want a postblit that gets the target instance its own distinct handle to the same file, so that copy construction works with those value semantics. Even in this case you would not need opAssign because postblit would be written to give true deep copy (value semantics).